# How to properly use multiple setInterval's to run different functions at different intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, raspberry-pi

I've built a webpage to run on a digital calendar I've built for a Raspberry Pi. The webpage contains, 2 calendar feeds, the current weather, and time/date.

The problem I'm having is I have each function set to run at different intervals but after a few hours the web page freezes up. I can still SSH into the Pi and use the Pi but the webpage becomes unresponsive.

The basis of the intervals are set like this:

```
// Update time every 1 second using MomentJS
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

// Update background every 10 seconds
setInterval(randombg, 10000)

// Update Calendar every 30 seconds
setInterval(calendarRefresh, 30000)
```

Any help is appreciated, cheers

Full code below as requested:

```
var app = angular.module('SmartCal', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

    //=========================
    // Backgrounds
    //=========================
    $scope.randombg = function () {
        $('body').css('background', 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(images/' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 1) + '.jpg)')

    }

    setInterval(function () {
        $scope.randombg();
    }, 10000)
    $scope.randombg();

    //=========================
    // Clock
    //=========================

    const weekdayName = $('.weekdayName');
    const dateNumber = $('.dateNumber');
    const month = $('.month');
    const year = $('.year');
    const time = $('.time');


    function update() {
        weekdayName.html(moment().format('dddd'));
        dateNumber.html(moment().format('D'));
        month.html(moment().format('MMMM'));
        year.html(moment().format('YYYY'));
        time.html(moment().format('h:mm:ss a'));
    }

    setInterval(update, 1000);


    //=========================
    // Get Calendars
    //=========================

     const calendar = $('#calendar');
     const calendarlist = $('#calendarlist');

    $scope.getCalendar = function () {
        calendar.fullCalendar({
            eventSources: [{
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '#',
                    googleCalendarId: '#'
                },
                {
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '#',
                    googleCalendarId: '#'
                }
            ],
            defaultView: 'month',
            height: 500,
            header: false
        });

        calendarlist.fullCalendar({
            eventSources: [{
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '#',
                    googleCalendarId: '#'
                },
                {
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '#',
                    googleCalendarId: '#'
                }
            ],
            defaultView: 'list',
            duration: {
                days: 30
            },
            height: 400,
            header: false
        });
    }

    //=========================
    // Calendar Refresh
    //=========================
    $scope.calendarRefresh = function () {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
        calendarlist.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
    }

    //=========================
    // Init
    //=========================

    $scope.getCalendar();

    $interval(function () {
        $scope.calendarRefresh();
    }, 30000);

});
```

Comment: Have you run a performance analysis to see what's sucking all the resources after the beginning? That's probably where to start, maybe there's a memory leak

Comment: That's probably my next logical step. I've been on a trial and error process by disabling each setInterval one by one to see whats happening. And if I just have the time running, so only one "setInterval" running then it seems to be fine. So I thought I could possibly be overloading the setIntervals somehow by having multiple.

Comment: @CyrisXD , will you please also post your functions ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi have added, thanks

Comment: You should use the `$interval` service instead of `setInterval` directly. For one thing, the former triggers a digest cycle. That being said, I'm not seeing much use for [tag:angularjs] in any of this

Comment: @Phil Thanks will give that a try. The codes a bit messed up right now with all the trial and error. Will fix it up

Comment: Why not just update a counter variable that keeps track of the seconds so you only would only need one interval...

Comment: Why are you mixing `setInterval` with `$interval`? Use only `$interval` as it is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.